# how to move element in dom and on screen with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Lets say I have a "p" tag like this:

```
<div id = "example">
    <p id = "eg">This is a text example.</p>
</div>
```

If I later insert other elements into that div is it possible to move the paragraph tag somewhere else in the dom, and it be visible to the user where I want it. So the result should be like this:

```
<div id = "example">
    <p id = "eg1">Another block of text.</p>
    <p id = "eg">This is a text example.</p>
    <p id = "eg2">Yet another block of text.</p>
</div>
```

So not only do I want to move it around...perhaps even into another div or different area of the page, but I also would like the ability to make sure that the user sees the text exactly as I want them too...maybe moved to the bottom or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to move an element from one position to another you can simply do the following:

```
$("#eg1").after($("#eg"));
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fhuzg/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You can't exactly "move" elements in jQuery (as far as I know), *per se*, but you can remove them and insert them somewhere else.

```
$("#eg").remove().insertAfter("#eg1");
```

EDIT: This is not true. You *can* move DOM elements wherever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Any change you make to the DOM will be reflected on the screen. You don't have to handle that separately.